# Axioms in Apache Jena

Tags: java, jena, owl

How can I create axioms such as

[image]

[image]

in Apache Jena in Java? Unfortunately, I don't really know OWL or RDF but I have to create an ontology, where certain class (e.g. *Cold*) sometimes is a subclass of *Positive* class and sometimes of *Negative* class. How can I add the (conditional) parent classes for *Cold*?

Comment: 1) obviously the image is almost not readable. Not sure what prevents you from writing text here ... 2) its Description Logic syntax, you should make familiar with it and which concept in OWL the operators represent. 3) how to use OWL in Apache Jena is documented here: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/ - there you can find how to add subclass axioms and create intersections of classes (spoiler both terms are exactly what the DL operators mean) 4.) once you found the solution, please post it here. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The first statement reads (the class) *Positive* is equivalent to the intersection of (the classes) *Cold* and *Beer*.

To represent the equivalence you can use:

```
OntClass.equivalentClass
```

and to create the intesection between two classes you can use:

```
OntModel.createIntersectionClass
```

For details see the link provided by @UninformedUser

Most commonly though you'd load this from RDF:

```
:Positive rdf:type owl:Class ;
          owl:equivalentClass [ owl:intersectionOf ( :Beer :Cold ) ] .
```

Comment: By the way, jena `OntModel` is about OWL1, while the most modern specification is OWL2. E.g. the method `OntModel#createIntersectionClass` allows to create a named `owl:intersectionOf`, that is not possible in OWL2, and may lead to problems (Protege is for OWL2). [ONT-API](https://github.com/owlcs/ont-api) allows to work with OWL2 in Jena.